# View JSON differences when HTTP testing in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I am running some HTTP tests in Laravel 5.4, mainly using the [assertJson helper method](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/http-tests) with phpunit. When I run other tests on my models using [assertEquals](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.assertions.html#appendixes.assertions.assertEquals) I usually get very good feedback about specifically which properties, fields, etc. are different than expected. However, the `assertJson` method only tells me that there *are* differences, but not *what* those differences are. For instance, let's say I have a route `my/route` that returns this JSON:

```js
{
  "name": "test",
  "foo": "bar"
}
```

I might run this Laravel test:

```php
$response = $this->get("my/route");

$response->assertJson([
    'name' => 'test',
    'foo' => 'baz',
]);
```

My test fails as expected. However, the resulting message is pretty unhelpful:

```
Failed asserting that an array has the subset Array &0 (
    'name' => 'test'
    'foo' => 'baz'
).
```

For a non-trivial example with larger response, it can get pretty annoying to try to figure out what is different between the JSON responses. Is there any way to view the specific differences between the expected and actual outputs, instead of just knowing that *something* is different between the two?

Comment: Will you JSON response be multidimensional?

Comment: @RossWilson Yes, probably. This is for all http testing in general, not one specific request, but I definitely have routes that return multidimensional JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your assertion in a `try-catch` and then if the assertion fails you'll be able to create a new message and throw a new exception.

```
/**
 * @test
 * @group new
 */
public function testExample()
{
    $response = $this->get('test');

    try {
        $expected = [
            'name' => 'test',
            'foo'  => 'barz',
        ];

        $response->assertJson($expected);
    } catch (\Exception $e) {

        $exporter = new \SebastianBergmann\Exporter\Exporter();

        $message = 'The following items we\'re expected to be different ' .
            $exporter->export($this->arrayRecursiveDiff($expected, $response->decodeResponseJson()));

        throw new \PHPUnit_Framework_ExpectationFailedException($message);
    }
}

public function arrayRecursiveDiff($array1, $array2)
{
    $return = [];

    foreach ($array1 as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($array2) && array_key_exists($key, $array2)) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $recursiveDiff = $this->arrayRecursiveDiff($value, $array2[$key]);
                if (count($recursiveDiff)) {
                    $return[$key] = $recursiveDiff;
                }
            } else {
                if ($value != $array2[$key]) {
                    $return[$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $return[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    return $return;
}
```

Please note the `arrayRecursiveDiff` method isn't fully tested, however, there are quite a few different examples floating around for how to compare multidimensional arrays.

Hope this helps!